# Bootstrap не работает при отправке mail

Tags: php, css, bootstrap4

Есть код: https://jsfiddle. net/9ndtqbay/. При отправки mail он не работает т.е выводится как есть:
[image: 123]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно. Письма верстаются так скажем в старом формате, с табличной вёрсткой и старым сбособом, ещё до всяких бутстрапов, флексов и пр.

Это позволяет быть письмам быть лёгкими и не нагружать почту всяким хламом.

А уж подключение в шапке всяких скриптов тем более не позволительно, чтобы кому-то в письмо не прилетела ссылка на какой-то вирус непонятный.

Поэтому забудьте про бутстрап и про встраивание всяких script и link и посмотрите в сети тему на счёт того как правильно верстаются письма. **Вёрстка писем не такая же, как обычная вёрстка**

---

Можно конечно сэмулировать бустрап и вставить много кода в тег styles, как то https://github.com/advancedrei/BootstrapForEmail,  но за это пользователи спасибо не скажут.